# Grabbing everything before keyword and predetermined number of spaces

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have two statements:

```
Greg Wylde hits the penalty kick with his left foot to the lower left corner and scores!!

Robin van Persie powers the penalty kick with his right foot to the upper right corner and scores!!
```

And I want to grab

```
Greg Wylde

Robin van Persie
```

The only thing I can guarantee is that every sentence will have `penalty kick` in the sentence and then two words before that (`hits the`, `places the`, `shoots the` and so on).

Essentially the sentence will always take this form:

`Name (can be n amount of words) someWord someWord penalty kick`

How would I go about writing a regex to pull out the name.

Currently I have something along the lines of

```
 [^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]*(?<=penalty)
```

which gets me to the last space after the name, but how do I just tell it to grab everything before that? I'm sure it's super simple but I'm completely missing it.

Thank you!

Comment: Does `^(.*?)` do the trick?

Comment: @Ryan just adding that to the front of the Regex doesn't seem to be grabbing anything.

EDIT: YES it does I had a weird space in my code! Thank you so much this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://regex101.com/r/KtNoCS/1) regex works for me:

```
(\w+\s\w+)[\w\s]+penalty kick
```

It works by capturing the first two words of the sentence, and matching some mix of words and spaces before "penalty kick".

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best regex out there but it should work. Tested with [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

```
.+?(?= [^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]*(?<=penalty))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `^(.*?) \w+ \w+ penalty`, i.e.:

```
import re
sentence = "Greg Wylde hits the penalty kick with his left foot to the lower left corner and scores!!"
result = re.findall(r"^(.*?) \w+ \w+ penalty", sentence , re.DOTALL)
print result[0]
# Greg Wylde
```

---

[Python Demo](https://ideone.com/XvsmuA)

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lDKYm0/1/)